# How to store a substring given a delimiter in C

Tags: c, string, performance, memory, delimiter

Let's say I have a series of data that's in this form:

```
"SomethingIDontCareAbout : SomethingICareAbout"
```

where the part after the ":" can vary in length of course.

The goal here is only storing the "SomethingICareAbout" substring efficiently. I made this function but the problem is that I'm storing both substrings,so it seems like a waste of memory. Any help to reduce to the time/space complexity?

```
char** ExtractKey(char* S)           
{
    int n = strlen(S);
    int count = 0, i = 0, j = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(S[i] == ':')
            break;
        
        count++;
    }
    char** T = (char**)malloc(2 * sizeof(char*));

    T[0] = (char*)malloc((count + 1)  * sizeof(char));
    T[1] = (char*)malloc((n - count) * sizeof(char));

    for(i = 0; i < count; i++)                          // inefficient ? cus we won't need T[0] [j]
    {
        T[0][j] = S[i];
        j++;
    }
    T[0][j+1] = '\0';
    j = 0;
    for(i = count + 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        T[1][j] = S[i];
        j++;
    }
    T[1][j+1] = '\0';
    return T;
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just allocate a new string of length `n - i + 1` and copy the substring you care about into that? Why do you need to have this double pointer?

Comment: Oh I needed that beforehand, but now I wanted to adjust it and for some reason I got lost in what to remove, also n -  i + 1 is just obvious, I don't know why I love adding counters for no reason, thanks for the tip !

Comment: Are you required to write such a function from scratch or can you just use standard C functions such as `strtok`?

Comment: 'strtok' splits the string into substrings according to a delimiter, and each one occupies a line. That's not what I really want, because essentially my string is a "Key : Value" type..and I only wanna compare the "value" to some user input later in the process of a searching algorithm..

Comment: @smurf3K For that, you don't need to make a copy of the substring, just a pointer to the value part of the original string would suffice. You would get better suggestions if you edited the question to ask what you really want to achieve there..

Comment: Instead of using strtok which modifies the original string maybe you want to use strchr to get a pointer to the delimiter (or strpbrk if there might be more than one), increment the pointer by the delimiter size, and then do the strcmp with the target.

Comment: I guess it also depends on whether there are ALWAYS spaces around the colon or not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason to invent a search for a character in a string, or a copy of a string.

If the input data will live long enough for you to use the "value" part, just return a pointer to the value:

```
char* ExtractKey(char* S)           
{
  return strchr(S, ':');
}
```

If it doesn't, or if you for some reason need a separate copy:

```
char* ExtractKey(char* S)           
{
  return strdup(strchr(S, ':'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, this could be done efficiently if `strtok()` was used to split those strings. I have designed the following code that parses each string of a 2-D array with a common delimiter that is `:` here.

Now, let's take a look into the code (notice the comments):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LEN 128

int main(void) {
    // The 2-D string
    char str[][MAX_LEN] = {"SomethingElse : SomethingToCareAbout",
                           "Something2 : SomethingToCare2",
                           "Unnecessary : Necessary"};
    int size = sizeof(str) / sizeof(str[0]);

    // Applying Variable-Length Array (valid in C)
    char store_cared_ones[size][MAX_LEN];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        // Declaring a temporary pointer variable to obtain the required
        // substring from each string
        char *sub_str = NULL;
        sub_str = strtok(str[i], ": ");
        sub_str = strtok(NULL, ": ");

        // Copying the 'sub_str' into each array element of 'store_cared_ones'
        strcpy(store_cared_ones[i], sub_str);
    }

    // Displaying each of 'store_cared_ones'
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", store_cared_ones[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Finally, let's see what that code does:

```
rohanbari@genesis:~/stack$ ./a.out
SomethingToCareAbout
SomethingToCare2
Necessary
```

Comment: I never worked with strtok before, but I did see some if its applications nevertheless, and the part I struggle to understand is this one: ' sub_str = strtok(NULL, ": "); '
Can you clarify what that does exactly

Comment: @BeyondCrisp A null pointer is always specified, so the function continues scanning where a previous successful call to the function ends.